# Need help extracting information out of a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm currently working on a client/server application in C#, it deals with computer spec registrations and sends packets of data from client to server.

After I receive the packets I extract and split them information into relevant string except that I need to extract them further. So I have a case where I have a string like this one:
 `{2,(IDT High Definition Audio CODEC,IDT),(High Definition Audio Device,Microsoft)}`

So the audio data is encapsulated within curly brackets "{", and the # number after the opening curly bracket suggest how many sound devices there are within a system, and for each sound device a bracket pair is opened and those are divided by a comma where as each information within the brackets is also divided by a comma as well.

So what I need to be able to do, is from the upper mentioned string to extract the information that are within the brackets themselves as many pairs as there are.
So out of:

```
{2,(IDT High Definition Audio CODEC,IDT),(High Definition Audio Device,Microsoft)}
```

To get:

```
string[] array = new array{"IDT High Definition Audio CODEC,IDT","High Definition Audio Device,Microsoft"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I explain the code in the comment.

```
    // Input string
    string input = "{2,(IDT High Definition Audio CODEC,IDT),(High Definition Audio Device,Microsoft)}";

    // Remove the last }
    input = input.Remove(input.Length - 1);

    // Remove from the begining to the first (
    input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('('));

    // Remove the first and the last characters
    input = input.Remove(0, 1);
    input = input.Remove(input.Length - 1);

    // At this point, the input value is
    // "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC,IDT),(High Definition Audio Device,Microsoft"

    // Split it, using "),(" as separators
    string[] data = input.Split(new[] { "),(" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Now, what you want is in data
    foreach (var s in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by a regular expression:

```
string s = "{2,(IDT High Definition Audio CODEC,IDT),(High Definition Audio Device,Microsoft)}";
string[] array = Regex.Matches(s, @"\((?<text>.*?)\)").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["text"].Value).ToArray();
```

Of course, this only looks for text in brackets `(` `)`. If the format of the returned string can be more complicated than the example you've shown, more elaborate parsing might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by `)|(` to get the desired result. Regex is an overkill here.

You should also remove `{#,(` from the beggining of the string and `)}` from the end.

```
//Instantiate vars
string audioData = "{2,(IDT High Definition Audio CODEC,IDT),(High Definition Audio Device,Microsoft)}";
int fromChar = audioData.IndexOf("("); //get text after first "("
audioData = audioData.Substring(fromChar + 1, audioData.Length - fromChar - 3); // .. to the last ")"

//Split and remove first and last item in array
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"),("};
string[] array = audioData.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MYW14719)